# Appending list to column of a CSV file

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-analyst, csv, arcgis-pro

There are 5 polygons in a shapefile. I am extracting the mean value of the NDVI pixel inside each polygon using "zonal statics as table". At this moment, I have 3 NDVI files, thus, I will get 3 sets of values. The codes are as follow

```
NDVI = ['1.tif', '2.tif', '3.tif']
poly_shape  = "polygon.shp"
table = r"E:\dump.gdb\NDVI_table.dbf"


for NDVI_file in NDVI:
    arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(poly_shape, "FID", NDVI_file, table, "DATA", "MEAN")
    single_list = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, "MEAN")]
```

As you can see, in each pass of the for loop I am getting one new list. I would like to create a CSV file to store the values. After each pass, I want to assign the values of the list in a new column.

To make it clear, after 1st pass, I will get the list below

```
single_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

after 2nd pass

```
single_list = [6,7,8,9,10]
```

after 3rd pass

```
single_list = [11,12,13,14,15]
```

I want the csv file to look like the following table (the first row will act as header and contain the raster file name)

```
1.tif   2.tif   3.tif
1       6       11
2       7       12
3       8       13
4       9       14
5       10      15
```

Is there any way to do that? I am using both ArcMap 10.6 and ArcGIS Pro 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) module which is included in 10.6 and Pro:

> pandas is an open source, BSD-licensed library providing
>   high-performance, easy-to-use data structures and data analysis tools
>   for the Python programming language.

```
import arcpy
import pandas as pd

NDVI = ['1.tif', '2.tif', '3.tif']
poly_shape  = "polygon.shp"
table = r"E:\dump.gdb\NDVI_table.dbf"

df = pd.DataFrame() #Create empty data frame

for NDVI_file in NDVI:
    arcpy.gp.ZonalStatisticsAsTable_sa(poly_shape, "FID", NDVI_file, table, "DATA", "MEAN")
    single_list = [i[0] for i in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, "MEAN")]
    df[NDVI_file] = pd.Series(single_list) #Add new column named after file and fill with values from list

df.to_csv(r'C:\folder\csvfile.csv', index=False) #Save as csv
```

Comment: It saved lots of hassle. Previously I have been using extra 10 lines of codes where it can do the same job with only two lines.